# Dismissing a Modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Goodevening

In IOS6.0 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) is deprecated. Sadly i can't find any other solution on the internet. Anybody any toughts? I have a closebutton with a method. In that method the modalview should be closed.

Making of button:

```
    UIButton *closeBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 50)];
    closeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeModalView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:closeBtn];
```

And the method:

```
     - (void)closeModalView:(id)sender{
          //This is deprecated
          [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: "Sadly i can't find any other solution on the internet" Did you even try? This information is not exactly hiding.

Comment: Why are you looking on the internet? How about the UIViewController Class Reference? Or how about the code completion in Xcode -- if you type self dismissMod..., by the time you get there, you'll get a popup showing you the correct method.

Answer (score 4):

New method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil`

Apple replaced the method so you can do things like show an alert view after the view has been dismissed:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:..] show];
}];
```